# TMediaPlayer - как получить доступ к аудиоданным?

Tags: c++builder, delphi, аудио

Как получить доступ к ТЕКУЩИМ аудиоданным при использовании компонента TMediaPlayer?
Задача: по таймеру копировать часть данных из аудиобуфера, ожидающих воспроизведения

Есть ли такая возможность именно при использовании компонента TMediaPlayer?

Comment: Вы хотите хранить в буфере целые треки?  
Может стоит попробовать сделать переменную (массив или стринглист) в которой бы хранились адреса треков, и потом просто пробегать по ней?

Comment: вероятно, компонент TMediaPlayer создает при проигрывании mp3, wav, других файлов буфер, в которых хранятся текущие проигрваемые данные, приведенные к одинаковому виду - как я надеюсь, к выборкам; хотелось бы периодически копировать часть этих выборок, например, по 4096 штук